# How do I print the number of characters based user input in c++?

Tags: c++

I am making a project to where the user enters a number and prints the that amount using `*`?

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    cin >> "Enter a number">>x;

    for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++) {
        cout <<"*"<< i;


    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: You haven't described what is your problem, actually.

Comment: You're not really asking a question here. I think first you should get some understanding of how the iostream library works. Find and read a basic tutorial, go through the examples, etc.

Comment: change it to `cout << "Enter a number:"; cin >> x;`

Comment: ah ok I see. I was working on it last night. I didn't see that small error until now.

Comment: but can you please up my vote.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem 1: Loop conditions**

```
for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
```

It will make an extra `*`. Imagine, how many integers between 0 and 5, inclusively? There are 6 - 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.

You need to either change your loop to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) { // C++ good practice
```

or

```
for (int i = 1; i <= x; i++) { // not C++ practice
```

The first one is a C++ good practice and should be used in almost all cases.

**Problem 2: Wrong output**

You have the following output:

```
cout << "*" << i;
```

which will produce something like

```
*0*1*2*3*4*5
```

According to your task, you want to simply output `x` asterisks.
Then, why do you output `i`?

**Problem 3: Wrong input**

You have a string in your `cin`. It is not a proper syntax. You need to split your output and input and use `cout` and `cin`, respectively.

**This code should work well:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    cout << "Enter a number"; 
    cin >> x;

    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        cout << "*";
    }
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: +1. and don't forget to check for errors when using `cin >> int` else you will get 0 when the user enters a non-valid character